# How to make a coroutine / task trigger a python discord bot to send a message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot that will use Selenium to check if some websites have some appointments available, this check is performed every 5 minutes on multiple websites. What I am struggling with is finding a way to running the `check_all()` function without causing the bot to be blocked for too long. What I think is a solution is to have the discord task run every 5 minutes and have it trigger some kind a function which will run the `check_all()` separate from the discord bot and then notify the discord bot as soon as it is done, that way the bot can do other things while the checks are being run. **What would be the simplest way to achieve this result?** 
Another even simpler solution would be to have two coroutines, one for the python bot and another for the check, the checking coroutine would update some local database with the info about the availability of appointments in each site, and the python bot would simply read that database instead of performing the checks itself. **Is this a better solution? How can I maintain these two coroutines given that one of them is a python bot?**

Looking forward to your answers!

Code is below:

```py
@tasks.loop(minutes=5)
async def send_message():
  # discord debug channel (probably a bad idea?)
  channel_debug = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name='debug')
  current_time = datetime.now(BerlinTz)
  formatted_time = current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  await channel_debug.send(f'{formatted_time}: Checking all cities ...')
  
  # actually using Selenium to check all the websites for each city (This is what I want to improve)
  response_task = asyncio.create_task(check_all(data))
  await response_task
  response = response_task.result()

  # checking for which cities the messages will be sent
  city_availability = check_availability(response)
  await channel_debug.send(city_availability)
  await channel_debug.send(response)
  # sending the messages for each city
  for entry in city_availability:
    if entry['send_msg_flag'] == True:
      print(entry['city'], "is available")
      channel_city = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name=entry['city'].lower()) 
      filtered_response = [element for element in response if element['city'].lower() == entry['city'].lower()]
      formatted_output = format_data(filtered_response)
      await channel_city.send(formatted_output)
    else:
      print(entry['city'], "is NOT available")
```

Tried using asyncio.create_task() but couldn't figure out how to make it leave the bot alone.

Comment: if your check_all() function contains blocking code, why not use `run_in_executor` to run it? It will not block the main event loop (which is your bot one), and it can also return an `asyncio.Future` object.